# GLTF doesn't render, stuck in blue loading screen

Tags: aframe, gltf

I'm trying to load a GLTF model into an A-Frame script.

Here is my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.2.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a-scene>
      <a-assets>
        <a-asset-item id="guiana" src="/assets/guiana.glb"></a-asset-item>
      </a-assets>

      <a-entity gltf-model="#guiana"></a-entity>
    </a-scene>
  </body>
</html>
```

In my project folder I have an assets subfolder with the guiana.glb file.

Upon dropping the index.html into Chrome I get stuck in a blue loading screen:

[image]

Any debugging tips would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it is a cross-site scripting issue (which you can tell by looking at the developer tools console). One way to fix it is by uploading your .GLB file somewhere else and including the full URL in the index.html.